# Cyclical grind sound when stopping

Tags: brakes, noise, kia, disk-brakes

I have a 2014 Kia Rio hatchback.

Over the last year I have been experiencing a very intermittent problem.

Sometimes, when I apply the brakes to come to a stop (say between 50 - 10 kph), there is a cyclical rough grind noise. It sounds like it happens every rotation of the wheel, as it gets slower as I slow down.

It sort of sounds like it comes from the back right disc brake.

The confusing thing is that it is very very intermittent. It has not happened for like 5 months, and then it just came back very pronounced...

Is it possible the it is large chunks of rusted rotor coming off and somehow creating the noise?

When I did my tire rotation I did notice slight binding on part of the rotor rotation, indicating a moderately warped rotor.

Comment: Did the read brake pads look ok? Not to thin and worn out?

Comment: Ya the brake pads looked good.

Comment: It can be rust if you live in rainy or humid climates.

Comment: The edges of the rotors are very rusty and flakey. I just dont know how a piece of rust would make a sound so audible, and cyclical.

Comment: Depending on the disc Pad compound, they can form rust on the surface of the pad also.

Comment: Ya that does happen to me, but it makes a much more subtle contstant sound that goes away after a few stops.

Comment: I'm convinced it is rust, next time it needs a rear break job replace the rotors and pick ceramic brake pads.